# AWS DynamoDB Strange Behavior -- Provisioned Capacity & Queries

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have some strange things occurring with my AWS DynamoDB tables. To give you some context, I have several tables for an AWS Lambda function to query and modify. The source code for the function is housed in an S3 bucket. The function is triggered by an AWS Api.

A few days ago I noticed a massive spike in the amount of read and write requests I was being charged for in AWS. To be specific, the number of read and write requests increased by 3,000 from what my tables usually experience (they usually have fewer than 750 requests). Additionally, I have seen similar numbers in my Tier 1 S3 requests, with an increase of nearly 4,000 requests in the past six days.

Immediately, I suspected something malicious had happened, and I suspended all IAM roles and changed their keys. I couldn't see anything in the logs from Lambda denoting it was coming from my function, nor had the API received a volume of requests consistent with what was happening on the tables or the bucket.

When I was looking through the logs on the tables, I was met with this very strange behavior relating to the [provisioned write and read capacity of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGnXi.jpg). It seems like the table's capacities are ping ponging back and forth wildly as shown in the photo.

I'm relatively new to DynamoDB and AWS as a whole, but [I thought I had set the table up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei51W.jpg) with very specific provisioned write and read limits. The requests have continued to come in, and I am unable to figure out where in the world they're coming from.

Would one of you AWS Wizards mind helping me solve this bizarre situation?

Any advice or insight would be wildly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out refreshing the table that appears in the DynamoDB management window causes the table to be read from, hence the unexplainable jump in reads. I was doing it the whole time ‍♂️